# Translating and comparing the sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, korean-to-english

I need some examples of how to translate the two sentences below:

다음에 연습 좀 해와요.

박서준 씨나 제대로 연습해 오세요.

Would you translate the first one as ‘Next time you should come and get more practice’? What else can it mean, depending on the context? Can you translate it as ‘next time please practice more’ to imply that someone’s bad at something and they should come over and practice once again’?

How about the second the one? Does it mean ‘Mr Park Seo Joon, please practice properly’? If you say this to Mr Park Seo Joon, can you use it to imply that Mr Park Seo Joon is bad at something and he should do better/practice more?

As always, would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

The order is important here: "XX해 오다" means "to do XX *and* come (with its result)".  E.g.,

> 낚시하러 가서 **메기 한 마리를 잡아왔다** = Went to fishing and **came back with a catfish.**

> 배고파서 나가서 **간식을 사왔다** = Was hungry, so [I] went out and **bought some snack** (and came back with it).

So "연습을 해 오다" means "practice *and then* come (with something to show for the practice)," or "practice before coming."  So, "다음에 연습 좀 해와요" means, "*Please* do some practice before we meet the next time."  Here, I think 좀 shows mild annoyance, as in, "We wasted our time because you weren't prepared.  *Please* do better next time!"

The answer also shows annoyance in return: "[박서준 씨]나" means something like "no, YOU", so "박서준 씨나 제대로 연습해 오세요." is like "Why don't YOU practice properly [before we meet the next time]?"

Comment: I see! Then, can you translate "연습을 해 오다" as "make sure you practice before the next time" and "박서준 씨나 제대로 연습해 오세요" as "you're the one who should practice" ? Would "make sure" work in the first example?

Comment: Sounds good to me - the situation is that the first speaker is upset that the second person didn't practice enough, so I think your sentences capture the intention well enough.

Comment: I see, thanks for helping me out!! >:)